# Right join with a where clause

Tags: sql, join

I found a query like this in code:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM a
        RIGHT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
  WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Is it basically the same as an inner join on a.id = b.id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is basically the same as an `inner join`.

The `where` clause will fail when there are no matches, because the value `a.id` will be `NULL`.